# Backbone.js Application takes up to 30% CPU performance

Tags: backbone.js

I am working on a Backbone.js application which is nearly done by now. My problem is that it seems like my application requires a lot of CPU performance. A regular Macbook Air takes up to 30% CPU if you visit my website (the Firefox process).

I can't think of any reason for this. I have like 6-7 different Views and a table with like 60 Views (each entry/row is a View object). Also I use setInterval() to fetch updates from the API every 10 seconds, but they're in total 4 HTTP requests with a content-length of ~1000, which should be totally acceptable.

According to Backbone-Eye I have 66 Models, 67 Views, 4 Collections, 1 Router. Also I took a "Javascript CPU profile" and it seems that a lot of CPU performance is used for rendering/painting, but with no information how to reduce it.

I would appreciate any tips how to reduce CPU load in my Backbone App.

Answer (score 1):

- Stagger the 4 requests you make every 10 seconds.  Make each one of them poll between 9.8 to 10.2 seconds instead of doing them all at 10 seconds.
- After you do these 4 fetches check if the content has changed.  Only re-render the views if the content from your fetch has changed.
- Do you have view memory leaks, zombie views?  Do you properly close each row view?  [read How To: Detect Backbone Memory Leaks](http://andrewhenderson.me/tutorial/how-to-detect-backbone-memory-leaks/)

Comment: Yes. render is only called if a model has changed. But I'm not sure what you mean with 'close each row view'? Gonna read your link, thank you.